# Basil seeds turning wet in storage

Tags: seeds

I have harvested some basil seeds and i put them in an envelope in a glass jar. I closed the jar and for the first week it was looking fine. I went on holiday for 4 days and when i came back, the envelope was damp and there was this white, furry thing on the basil seeds. Could anyone help me with what this is?

Comment: Always leave your seeds out somewhere in the open to dry for a week or two before you put them away.

Comment: Don't discard the seeds just yet. They *might* still grow even with the fungus. But they also might be dead. Just "quarantine" them so they don't spread it to anything else, until planting time. And store them in a way that air flow can remove the moisture.

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have mold on your seeds. Apparently the remaining humidity was enough to get a nice mold colony going. If you want to keep your seeds, immediately let them dry out, but there’s no way to tell via the Internet whether the mold has affected only the outer shell of the seeds or also the inside. You could try germinating a small sample and then decide whether it’s worth the effort or not.

In any case, the seeds weren’t dry enough when you put them in the jar, next time make sure that the seeds are fully dry before moving them to sealed jars. I personally prefer small envelopes, but I have to make sure that they are also stored in a dry environment. If your storage area could be or become damp, jars are a good way to keep the seeds dry.

Comment: It it *must* be stored in a jar, throw in one of those "do not eat" bags that many products are packed with. It will absorb much of the trapped moisture

Answer (score 0):

The glass jar holds the moisture. That is why seeds are normally sold in paper envelopes, after complete drying. I have successfully put seeds in plastic bags after months of air drying.

Answer (score 0):

Basil seed, when exposed to moisture, will produce a bluish-white gelatinous slime around themselves. So whatever is on your seeds may not be mold. Seeds should never be stored in air-tight containers unless they are perfectly dry. The slimy seeds are used in the local cuisines in India and other places.
https://aeroponicsdiy.com/basil-seed-germination-covered-with-white-slime-gooey-mucilage-is-it-normal/